# Nuance naturally speaking SDK WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am developing a wpf app and i want to add speech to text functionality. I want to achieve this using nuance naturally speaking SDK. Below is my requirement explained briefly, 
1) User speak out text and this should be typed on the screen in a rich text box control. 
2) User speak out command and program should execute the command logic, 
for example i have a list whose items are apple, mango, grape. Select an item from list using command 'list item mango'. 
My questions are, 
a) Do i have to use Dragon SDK Client (DSC) Edition to fulfill my requirement or is there any other SDK or API form nuance for this requirement. 
b) Can anyone please suggest a basic tutorial for me to start on this, like how to setup SDK and a sample application in wpf will be great.
I have no clue from where to start and how to implement this.

Comment: did you find an answer?  Their website is absolutely horrible for trying to find out about the sdk.  There must be internal fighting about whether to release it to compete with windows's built in, or to keep it separate.   I couldn't find if it's free, or if they charge per developer, per application, per application install, or what.  I did an "online chat" to find out and the "person" just responded with a generic "call during business hours" message and ended the session.  This is pretty bad.  I'd say we probably better stick to windows built-in speech recognition, which is nearly as good.